# Why won't content next to v-navigation-drawer be displayed?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to set up a navigation drawer on the left with content on the right. This template is called from a router-view (not sure if that makes a difference). The navigation drawer shows up perfectly but the "Content here" part does not show up. Not only does it not display, but I don't believe it even exists in the document anywhere. What am I doing wrong?

```
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer
        :clipped="true"
        enable-resize-watcher
        width="200"
        style="background-color:#e7e8ea"
  >
    <v-toolbar class="background darken-1" flat>
      <v-list>
        <v-list-tile>
          <v-list-tile-title class="title justify-center">
            Subjects
          </v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list>
    </v-toolbar>
    <v-divider></v-divider>
    <v-list>
      <v-list-tile
          v-for="subject in subjects"
          :key="subject.id"
          class="primary--text"
          :active="currentSubject==subject"
          active-class="active blue"
          v-on:click="selectSubject(subject)"
      >
        <v-list-tile-content>
          <v-list-tile-title >{{ subject.name }} {{currentSubject==subject}}</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile-content>
      </v-list-tile >
      <v-list-tile-title class="mt-3">
        <v-list-tile-content style="align-items: center">
          <addStationRotationsSubjectDialog v-on:subject-added="selectLatestSubject()" :teacher="teacher" :selectedClass="selectedClass"></addStationRotationsSubjectDialog>
        </v-list-tile-content>
      </v-list-tile-title>
    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
  <v-content>
    <v-container fluid>
      Content here
    </v-container>
  </v-content>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not use multiple html elements at root in your template.
vuejs only allows one root element so wrap your html in a div tag or single parent tag like `<v-layout></v-layout>`